# how to dynamically display data based on user input

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form (php file) that allows a user to add investment information into database.  The user selects an investment from a dropdown (investments previously entered into database), and enters other information and submits it to the database.  I want that when the user selects a certain investment, the initial date (information that is already in the database) will be displayed in the 'initial date' field.  I used javascript/ajax, but it's not working (nothing is showing up in the initial date field).  I used the code at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp as a model.  Attached is the code.  Also, would it be better to use Jquery? Thanks!
Here's the updates.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
 <style type="text/css">
     table, th, td
    {
        border:1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
 </style>
<title>Updates</title>


<script>
function showDate(str) {
if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("initialDate").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("initialDate").innerHTML = 
this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","get_date.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>



</head>
<body>
<?php 
include("session.php");
include("navbar.php");
?>

<form style="margin-top: 60px" action="updateDetails2DB.php" method="post">
<h2>Update</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date of Update</th>
        <td><input type="date" name="date" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>As Of</th>
        <td><input type="date" name="" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Occupancy %</th>
        <td><input type="number" min="0" max="100" name=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Investment</th>
        <td><select name="investment_name" onchange="showDate(this.value)">
                    <?php 
                        $sql = 'SELECT distinct deal_name FROM tbl_deal'; 
                        $result = mysqli_query($DBconnect, $sql);

                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                        {
                            echo "<option value=''>Select 
    Investment</option>";
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                 echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0] 
   </option>";   
                            }
                        }
                            else
                        {
                            echo "<option value=''>No Investments 
Found</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Entity Current Value</th>
        <td>$<input type="text" name="current_val" size="20" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Basis For Valuation</th>
        <td><select name="basis_for_valuation">
            <option value="NOI">NOI</option>
            <option value="Appraisal">Appraisal</option>
            <option value="Manager Rep">Manager Rep</option>
            <option value="Cap Rate">Cap Rate</option>
            <option value="Reduction">Reduction</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Initial Value</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Initital Date</th>
        <td><div id="initialDate"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Average Annual Change in Values</th>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
   <!--...more entries-->

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Data" class="btn">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the get_date.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
include("config.php");
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

if (!$DBconnect) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($DBconnect));
}

$sql="SELECT deal_date FROM tbl_deal WHERE deal_name = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($DBconnect,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['deal_date'];
}

mysqli_close($DBconnect);
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

The $DBconnect string is a global variable in the config.php/session.php, it works with all my other files/queries.

Comment: Get rid of all the HTML from `get_date.php` that script is basically a subroutine that shoudl return ONLY what it isintended to return i.e. `echo $row['deal_date'];`

Comment: _SMall Note_ If you aer only going to ereturn ONE row in your resultset you dont need to put your fetch in a while loop.

Comment: _Alternatively_ If that is supposed to return more than one row, buffer the data up in a variable `$buf .= $row['deal_date'];` and then echo `$buf` after the while loop

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I took away the HTML from get_date.php, but it's still not working.

Comment: When I try calling the showDate() function in the console, I get an 'undefined' message

Comment: tell us the actual message. What is undefined, and on which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caught the problem - in the get_date.php file, $q = intval($_GET['q']), which gives the integer value for q.  However, I'm working with strings, so it's not working.  I took out intval() and replaced it with $q = $_GET['q'] and it works!